# Orbital frequency of gravitational wave prior to merger

Tags: black-holes, orbital-motion, frequency, gravitational-waves

In the paper *[The basic physics of the binary black hole merger GW150914](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.01940)*

Equation [A5] states that
$$\dot \omega^3=\left(\frac{96}{5}\right)^3\frac{\omega^{11}}{c^{15}}\left(G\mathscr M\right)^5
\tag{A5}\label{A5}
$$

where $c$, $G$ and $\mathscr M$ are constants, $\omega$ is the orbital frequency (not angular frequency).

I tried to solve for $\omega$,
\begin{align}
\dot \omega & = \frac{96}{5}\frac{\omega^{11/3}}{c^{15/3}}(G\mathscr M)^{5/3}
\nonumber\\
\frac{d\omega}{dt} & = \frac{96}{5}\frac{(G\mathscr M)^{5/3}}{c^{15/3}}\omega^{11/3}
\nonumber\\
\frac{d\omega}{\omega^{11/3}} & =\frac{96}{5}\frac{(G\mathscr M)^{5/3}}{c^{15/3}}dt
\tag{01}\label{01}\\
\frac{-3}{8\omega^{8/3}} & =\frac{96}{5}\frac{(G\mathscr M)^{5/3}}{c^{15/3}}
\nonumber
\end{align}

and obtained
$$\omega=\left(\frac{-3}{8}\right)^{3/8}\frac{5c^{15/3}}{96(G\mathscr M)^{5/3}}\frac{1}{t^{3/8}}
\tag{02}\label{02}
$$

This result doesn't make much sense to me as it returns a negative value? Also according to the paper, it should increase with time.

Edit: figure 1 from the article, as you can prior to the peak amplitude, the frequency of the gravitational wave increases with time. Since the orbital frequency $\omega$ is half of it, $f_{GW}=2\omega_{orb}$, I expected $\omega$ also increases with time. [image]

Edit 2: fixed a typo in the first equation. Should be $\omega^{11}$

Comment: Your solution doesn’t appear to satisfy the equation. And what did you take as an initial condition?

Comment: What does the gravitational waveform look like at the end of the merger? Isn't it more of an exponential "thump"? Such a waveform doesn't have a well defined angular frequency at the end because the damping term dominates, so there should be an imaginary number in there somewhere. Just an experimentalist talking nonsense here, I guess.

Comment: @FlatterMann At the end of merger ringdown starts. But prior to merger, the wave frequency increases with time, and by extension the orbital frequency. I have included a figure from the article.

Comment: You can’t just ignore initial conditions when solving differential equations.

Comment: @HalcyonMo I understand that. Can I assume that the differential equation is only a good approximation before the ringdown? Or is it general? In the latter case there should be something imaginary popping up. That's all I am saying. If the approximation breaks, then it's fine with me, too.

Comment: @FlatterMann Yes equation [A5] was a Keplerian approximation, obtained by assuming the energy radiated away was small compared to orbital energy.

Comment: Got it! Thank you! I learned something new today.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because although about Physics it's a Mathematical question (solution of a 1st order differential equation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the algebra easier let's absorb all the constants into a single constant and write:

$$ \frac{d\omega}{dt} = k\omega^{11/3} $$

Then integrating gives:

$$ \tfrac{-8}{3}\omega^{-8/3} = kt + C $$

where $C$ is a constant to be determined from the initial conditions. Now redefine the constants $k$ and $C$ to include the $\tfrac38$ (and swap the sign of C) and we get:

$$ \omega = \frac{1}{(C - kt)^{3/8}} $$

This has the behaviour we expect. At time zero we get $\omega = 1/C^{3/8}$ and that fixes the constant $C$. Then as time goes by the denominator decreases, which means $\omega$ increases with time as expected. $\omega$ would increase to infinity at $t = C/k$, but presumably the approximation would have broken down by then.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Now I feel really silly asking a question like this. I don't think my question would help other people much in terms of physics, do you think it's better if I just delete this question?

Comment: @HalcyonMo In general we don't recommend deleting questions as the site keeps track of deleted questions and if a user has too many deleted questions they can be blocked. However deleting one question is probably fine, so if you'd prefer to delete this one go ahead.